# Kendo UI for Angular Datepicker Localization doesn't work when module is loaded via ngIf

Tags: angular6, kendo-ui-angular2

This question pertains to an Angular 6 app that uses Kendo UI for Angular.

I have been working recently to get the dynamic globalization/localization of Kendo's DatePicker and TimePicker components to work. In the top right corner of the site, in the header, there is a language dropdown that the user can change the language/locale of the site dynamically. I wanted to implement a way to dynamically update Kendo's datepicker and timepicker components to automatically translate the text and update the DateTime formats of the Kendo component according to the locale that the user selects from the dropdown.

So I took Kendo's DatePicker and TimePicker components and wrapped them in their own module called "DatepickerWrapperModule". And everything works fine as long as this module is eagerly loaded (i.e. the module and corresponding component is not dynamically injected into the page).

However, if the module and corresponding component is loaded dynamically into the page via the *ngIf directive, then it breaks the dynamic localization that I have set up.

I assume this is due to the module being lazy loaded and thus creating new instances of the services that it depends on??? But after researching and trying many different things to get it to work, I have been unsuccessful so far. Is there any way to get this type of Kendo UI DatePicker dynamic localization to work with modules/components that are dynamically loaded via *ngIf ???

Normally, I would supply all the relevant code examples, but they are way too large and complex to display concisely in this question. In general, there is:

- the **AppModule**
- a **SharedModule**
- and the **DatepickerWrapperModule**

The **AppModule** imports the SharedModule in the imports[] array, using the forRoot() method.

The **SharedModule** then imports the DatepickerWrapperModule in the imports[] array, and also exports it in the exports[] array. In the imports[] array, the DatepickerWrapperModule uses the forRoot() method.

The **DatepickerWrapperModule** then implements the DatePickerWrapper component, which contains the actual references to the Kendo DatePicker component.

Also, in the DatepickerWrapperModule's constructor, I am using @Optional() and @SkipSelf() constructor parameter decorators to see if the DatepickerWrapperModule is being loaded twice, and through some simple console.log statements, I confirmed that it is indeed getting initialized and loaded twice (once during the initial loading of the entire app/site, and once when the *ngIf condition is met on the particular page and for the particular component under consideration.

I would like to figure out how to get the module/component that loads via the *ngIf condition to use the instance of DatepickerWrapperModule that is already loaded as part of the entire app, instead of creating a new instance of it when the component is dynamically added to the DOM when the *ngIf condition is met.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the approach described [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1455#issuecomment-405247258)

Comment: @SiliconSoul Yes, after much trial and error, I finally found the problem and the specific place when I needed to provide the IntlService and CldrIntlService.

But yes, the approach described in the link you provided lead me in the right direction and eventually solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I finally solved my issue, I wanted to provide the answer to my own question that solved it for me, in case anyone else encounters this same issue in the future.

For reference, please see the recommended approach that eventually solved my issue here:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1455#issuecomment-405247258

Basically, the problem for me was related to how Lazy-Loaded Modules work when loaded via routes, such as:

```
{
    path: 'logistics',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    appData: 'APPDATA_LOGISTICS',
    loadChildren: './logistics/+logistics/logistics.module#LogisticsModule'
}
```

In the providers[] array of my AppModule, I have specified the **LOCALE_ID**, **CldrIntlService**, and **IntlService** as follows:

```
providers: [
    CldrIntlService,
    {
        provide: IntlService,
        useExisting: CldrIntlService
    },
    {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        useValue: 'en-US'
    }
]
```

This will provide these services to eagerly-loaded modules that are imported in AppModule or some child of AppModule, but for lazily-loaded modules that are not imported by or direct children of AppModule, it will create new instances of these services.

So, per the link above, once I specified the appropriate providers in the lazily-loaded LogisticsModule, the dynamic localization of the Kendo DatePicker and TimePicker components began working again as expected.

Here is the relevant part of the providers[] array in the LogisticsModule that resolved my issue:

```
providers: [

    .
    .
    .

    {
        provide: IntlService,
        useExisting: CldrIntlService
    }

    .
    .
    .

]
```

This tells the LogisticsModule to use the instance of the services already created (provided) in the AppModule (instead of creating new instances of the services when the module is lazy loaded).